# Bit Bucket - Commits are present in history but missing in the latest file

Tags: bitbucket

We are using Atlassian Bitbucket v8.9.9.
Recently, we have been facing issues because the committed changes are missing during the deployment.
When we did a backtracking of the Commits, these are available in the history but missing in the latest file even though none of the commits after that have deleted the previous content.

We observed that these commits dont show in the History drop down when Follow Renames Toggle is OFF. They are visible when the Follow Renames Toggle is ON.

[image]

[image]

From the above screens, we can see that Commits no. 1, 2 and 3 are missing from the history where Follow Renames is OFF.

Commit # 5 has the same content as Commit # 3 and has been added again since commit # 3 was missing during the deployment.

Can someone help us understand why this is happening or what we are going wrong with?

Looks like the main file only has the commits which are available in the history dropdown with Follow Renames OFF.